# Installing Laravel application on main domain (without using subdomains)

Tags: laravel

Server: DigitalOcean (Ubuntu)

I am setting a server. I have a Laravel application that is currently setup to be accessed via subdomain, e.g. subdomain.mydomain.com. But I would like to access my application from the main domain, not subdomain.

For instance: instead of subdomain.domain.com, I would like to use domain.com. Below is my 000-default.conf configuration.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/myapplication/public"
    <Directory "/var/www/html/myapplication/public/">
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.mydomain.com [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mydomain.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: If the answer worked for you, mark as "the answer" to close your question.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the configuration for the php interpreter. i suggest you copy your old subdomain config and just change `ServerName`, `ServerAlias`.

here's an example of what you are missing:

```
location ~ .php$ {
    set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
    root /var/www/html/myapplication/public;
    fastcgi_index app.php;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /app.php$is_args$args /index.php$is_args$args;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  }
```

Comment: That could be defined globally.   It's impossible to know how PHP is configured on the server from this question.

Comment: @Devon since some framework have their `index.php` or `app.php` in other places than the root folder, a global configuration for the PHP interpreter might not be the best idea. Especially if you have multiple installation in the same machine.